# partial string matching in R ,apart from using grep

Tags: r, string-matching

I need to do partial string matching R:

```
eg: str1<-"here we go"
    str2<-"here we go another way"
```

I need to do something like grep(str1,str2) ,i.e. the output should return whether str1 is in str2 or not. One way to do is grep but grep is running very slow. How could this be done in a faster way?

Thanks

Comment: is the common part always at the beginning of str1? (if so, maybe `substr(str2, 1, nchar(str1))==str1` is faster?)

Comment: Try adding `, fixed = TRUE`, though I'm surprised `grep` is slow. Are you running it within a loop?

Comment: Also try `stri_detect_fixed` in the stringi package.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grepl` for example. Here a wrapper function:

```
str1 <- "here we go"
str2 <- "here we go another way"

`%instr%` <- 
  function(s1,s2) grepl(s1,s2) || grepl(s2,s1)

str1 %instr% str2
## [1] TRUE
```